# Call java script function from the button id

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call myfunc() using the id button, how I do that? 
I dont want to use nothing but the id to call this function..what code I need to add in my script?

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script>
            function myfunc() {

                var count = 0;
                var line = 0;
                var i = 0;
                var phrase = document.getElementById('phrase').value;
                var filter = document.getElementById('filter').value;
                var arr = phrase.split(" ").reverse();

                for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

                    if (arr[i].search(filter) == -1) {
                        if (line % 2 == 0) {
                            document.getElementById('words').innerHTML += " <u><span class='word'  style='background:#D8D8D8; border:1px solid black; ' >
 " + arr[i] + "</span></u>";
                            line++;
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('words').innerHTML += " <span class='word'  style='background:#D8D8D8; border:1px solid black; '>
 " + arr[i] + "</span>";
                            line++;
                        }
                    }

                    if ((arr[i].search(filter) != -1) && (filter)) {
                        count++;
                    }

                }
                document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = count + " word(s) filtered out";

            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
         <h1>Sentence Reverser!</h1>

        <div>Phrase:
            <input id="phrase" type="text" size="40" />
        </div>
        <div>Filter:
            <input id="filter" type="text" size="10" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="go">Go!</button>
        </div>
        <div id="words"></div>
        <div id="count"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = myfunc
```

After the element has loaded. In practice this means below the element, or in the head within a window loaded event.

Comment: where exacly I need to add this ?

Comment: tnx! its working ! only need to add <body onload=func()>   and put your line inside the function

Answer (score 0):

To be as short as possible, you can add this script after the HTML, or in the document load event:

```
go.onclick = myfunc
```

But this is far from best practice. A better practice would be to add an onclick attribute to your button:

```
<button id="go" type="button" onclick="myfunc()"> Go! </button>
```

Comment: I know this way, but I need to call the function only with the id. tnx

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "only with the id"? because if I execute the code `go`, it will simply return the button. Not execute a function.

Comment: document.getElementById('go').onclick = myfunc;  //this line not working

Comment: Try moving your JavaScript below the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addEventListener()`  to attach the function on particular event inside the `window.onload`, something like this.

```
window.onload = function (){
    document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', myfunc);

    function myfunc(){
        //your all code be here
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5wk8W/)